# Splitting a line in python; only taking the first 4 values

Tags: python, regex

I have made a script that splits a long file into multiple tiny files. It always splits when there are exactly 4 integers. I want to improve it by stating that there are exactly 4 integers but only at the start of the line.

Sample input

```
1020                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
200123242151111231                                 bla             bla                                       bla
200123331231231441                                 bla             bla                                       bla
1030
200123242151111231                                 bla             bla                                       bla
200123331231231441                                 bla             bla                                       bla
```

Wished for output is the above content split in:

```
200123242151111231                                 bla             bla                                       bla
200123331231231441                                 bla             bla                                       bla
```

and

```
200123242151111231                                 bla             bla                                       bla
200123331231231441                                 bla             bla                                       bla
```

When one of the values of bla is 4 integers, then it adds an extra split. How do I make sure the re.split function only checks the first 4 or 5 values of a line.

```
import re

file = open('testnew.txt', 'r')

i=0
for x in re.split(r"\b[0-9]{4}\s+", file.read()):
    f = open('%d.txt' %i,'w')
    f.write(x)
    f.close()
    print (x,i)
    i = i+1
```

Comment: I think you need to split on a line that is equal to 4 digits. Try `r'(?m)^\d{4}$[\r\n]*'`

Comment: I can't believe that I can't find a duplicate for this question...

Comment: @Aran-Fey If my suggestion above is correct, it is hard to find a dupe for it. I rarely see such requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You think so? The question is just "how do I match only at the start of a line", isn't it? An answer about `^` and `re.M` would make a suitable duplicate, I think.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I see your point, but that won't be the right answer given the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to read the file line by line. That way, you won't run into issues with overloading your memory if the file is too big, and you can also run the 4 digit check on the line itself without the awkward splitting.

```
doc = 0
towrite = ""
with open("somefile.txt", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if len(line.strip()) == 4 and line.strip().isdigit():
            if i > 0:  # write txt from prior parse
                wfile = open("{}.txt".format(doc), "w")
                wfile.write(towrite)
                wfile.close()
            doc = line.strip()
            towrite = ""  # reset
        else:
            towrite += line
wfile = open("{}.txt".format(doc), "w")
wfile.write(towrite)
wfile.close()
```

Test file:

```
1234
43267583291483 1234 3213213
57489367483929 32133248 3728913
3267
32163721837362 4723 3291832
42189323471911 321113 3211111132
326189183828327 3218484828283 828238281
21838282387 3726173 6278
1111
1236274818 327813678
32167382167894829013 321
```

Results in:

**1234.txt**

```
43267583291483 1234 3213213
57489367483929 32133248 3728913
```

**3267.txt**

```
32163721837362 4723 3291832
42189323471911 321113 3211111132
326189183828327 3218484828283 828238281
21838282387 3726173 6278
```

**1111.txt**

```
1236274818 327813678
32167382167894829013 321
```

Comment: You are amazing; I spend all morning on this stuff and you just pop it out of your brain. Amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

^ matches the begin of a string

$ matches the end of a string

findall returns a list of all matches, if you use (capture groups), it returns the capture groups

(?:) are non-capturing groups

* is greedy, *? is not

This solution should work:

```
import re

file = open('testnew.txt', 'r')

i=0
for x in re.findall(r"((?:.|\n)*?)(?:(?:^|\n)\d{4}\n|$)", file.read()):
    if x: # skip empty matches
      f = open('%d.txt' %i,'w')
      f.write(x)
      f.close()
      print (x,i)
      i = i+1
```

Comment: thank you for the reaction. I tried that but not it does not split at all anymore. Trying to make it file.readline() in stead of file.read()

Comment: You can match the line break: "\n[0-9]{4}"

Comment: @user3109219 That won't match the first line, because the file doesn't start with a line break.

Answer (score 0):

Reading line by line will be good. You can check if string length is 4 then skip it.